# Create anchor links in Evernote

Tags: evernote

In Google Docs, you can insert a bookmark in the middle of the document and link to it. I don't think you can do this with Evernote. Am I wrong? I have some saved articles, and I want to be able to link to an exact paragraph of the article. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: If you've found the answer, please add it as an answer; don't add it to the question. Also, questions asking for app or tool recommendations are off-topic here. You'll want to try [softwarerecs.se].

Answer (score 1):

Anchor links have not been implemented officially by Evernote yet.

A work around is :

1. Create a sub-note for each of the paragraphs you want to (anchor) link to.
2. Create a Note Link ( Hyper link) to each of these SubNotes.
3. In the original note, you can create a Table of Contents at the top with the note links ( hyperlinks ) to all of your sub-notes.
4. From the other notes, you can either directly link to the sub notes you created , or refer to the index number in the Table of Contents at the top of your main note and link to it.

Not as neat as true HTML-like anchor links, but works decently well.